# Javascript - Exercise 1 of Advanced Javascript by Kyle Simpson

Tags: javascript

In exercise 1 of Kyle Simpson's (@kyle-simpson) Advanced JavaScript course [here](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/advanced-javascript/table-of-contents) , the objective of which is to expand understanding of scopes, hoisting etc. there are a couple of things I found hard to follow.

## Exercise files

#### ex1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Exercise 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Exercise 1</h1>
<script src="ex1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### ex1.js

```
A();

function C() {
    console.log("OOPS!");
}

function E(f) {
    console.log("E");
    f();
    var f = F;
}

var A = function() {
    console.log("A");
    B();
};

var C;

function G() {
    console.log("G");
    H();

    var H = function() {
        console.log("H");
        I();
    };
}

var D = d;

function d() {
    console.log("D");
    E();
}

function I() {
    console.log("I");
    J();
    J();
}

B = function() {
    console.log("B");
    C();
};

var F = function() {
    console.log("F");
    G();
};

var rest = "KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
for (var i=0; i<rest.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
        // define the current function
        window[rest[i]] = function() {
            console.log(rest[i]);
            if (i < (rest.length-1)) {
                // TODO: call the next function
            }
        };
    })(i);
}

var J = function() {
    J = function() {
        console.log("J");
        K();
    };
};

C = function() {
    console.log("C");
    D();
};
```

Instructions (README.md)

1. Fix the code so it prints out the alphabet A-Z in the console.
2. Cannot:

   - Have **any** global variables at all
   - Delete or combine any function declarations
   - Create any new functions (except IIFEs -- hint!)
   - Rearrange the order of declarations
3. Can/must:

   - Declare extra variables (as long as they're not global)
   - Modify (in-place) function declaration/initialization
   - Add/remove statements/expressions (IIFEs, return, params, etc)
   - Make the fewest changes possible

## Solution (only need to change ex1.js)

#### ex1-fixed.js

```
(function(global){

    function C() {
        console.log("OOPS!");
    }

    function E(f) {
        console.log("E");
        f();
        var f = F;
    }

    var A = function() {
        console.log("A");
        B();
    };

    var C;

    function G() {
        console.log("G");
        H();

        function H() {
            console.log("H");
            I();
        }
    }

    var D = d;

    function d() {
        console.log("D");
        E(F);
    }

    function I() {
        console.log("I");
        J();
        J();
    }

    B = function() {
        console.log("B");
        C();
    };

    var F = function() {
        console.log("F");
        G();
    };

    var rest = "KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split(""), fns = {};
    for (var i=0; i<rest.length; i++) {
        (function(i){
            // define the current function
            fns[rest[i]] = function() {
                console.log(rest[i]);
                if (i < (rest.length-1)) {
                    fns[rest[i+1]]();
                }
            };
        })(i);
    }

    var J = function() {
        J = function() {
            console.log("J");
            fns.K();
        };
    };

    function C() {
        console.log("C");
        D();
    }

    return A;

})(window)();
```

I follow the solution well enough till `I` gets printed.

#### Questions on part of the code after `I` gets printed

**1.**In the solution (and exercise code) the author uses the below function declaration for function `I` and for `J` a function expression is used. The function is in such a way that the assignment for function reference `J` is updated within the function itself to print 'J'. However, when calling `J` from within `I` - why does `J()` need to be called twice?

```
var J = function() {
            J = function() {
                console.log("J");
                K();
        };
    };

function I() {
        console.log("I");
        J();
        J();
    }
```

**2.** In the exercise code the author expect to fix the following lines of codes to get alphabets L to Z printed.

For each letter, an anonymous function is run to create a function name by the letter (for letters 'K' to 'Z' and stuck to window object - The part I don't understand is

1)when are these functions for each letter invoked - I see the invocation via the line `window[rest[i+1]]();` - but how we get here?

2)when a function for ith letter is created, we are invoking the function for i+1th letter (via `window[rest[i+1]]();`) which may be undefined at that point - but the code works and prints out letter L to Z

```
var rest = "KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
for (var i=0; i<rest.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
        // define the current function
        window[rest[i]] = function() {
            console.log(rest[i]);
            if (i < (rest.length-1)) {
                // TODO: call the next function
                window[rest[i+1]]();
            }
          };
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Whoa, what a horrible code :-)

Comment: Yes - it is deliberately horrible code to get the course students thinking about scope declarations vs statements & assignments and IFFEs.  The best place for this question is the discussion thread on the pluralsight course. https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/advanced-javascript/discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function is in such a way that the assignment for function reference `J` is updated within the function itself to print 'J'.

Exactly.

> However, when calling `J` from within `I` - why does `J()` need to be called twice?

The first call - as you said - only updates the `J` variable. The second call will actually call the updated function, the one that logs 'J' and continues with `K`.

> when are these functions for each letter invoked?

As you say, they get called "recursively" from inside those functions until `i` has reached the end. The first invocation, that starts the chain, is inside the `J` function from above:

```
fns.K();
```

(notice that `rest[0]` is `K`)

> when a function for ith letter is created, we are invoking the function for i+1th letter (via `window[rest[i+1]]();`) which may be undefined at that point

No. The invocation of the next function is inside the function that we are creating. Those functions are only created, they are not yet called from within the loop - the function call in there is that of the IIFE. They will be invoked from `J` after the loop has finished.

Answer (score 1):

> However, when calling J from within I - why does J() need to be called twice?

In the code example you gave below:

```
var J = function() {
            J = function() {
                console.log("J");
                K();
        };
    };

function I() {
        console.log("I");
        J(); // The first call refines the value of J
        J(); // This now calls the inner J instead
    }
```

In the `I` function what the first `J` call does is basically redefines what the function `J` is. After the first call is made the `J` function changes from:

```
function () {
    J = function() { // Here inside the call is where J is being redefined
        console.log("J");
        K();
    };
}
```

To:

```
function () {
    console.log("J");
    K();
}
```

That's why the second call is needed. Just note that every other function call to `J` will work fine and print `J` and call `K()`, so it's not very practical other than for learning purposes.

> When are these functions for each letter invoked - I see the invocation via the line `window[rest[i+1]]();` - but how we get here?

In this case the code you provided doesn't actually do anything. This is only creating the functions and not running any of them, hence why `window[rest[i+1]]` will be defined later along with that the condition `i < (rest.length-1)` will make sure there was not a call that is out-of-bounds.